# Why does addAll clear ArrayList pulling data from?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a Fragment sending an ArrayList, newStyles, to its FragmentActivity, mStyles, which is cleared then using addAll is stored. I have used .size() to check the Arrays and notice the source, newStyles, is cleared after addAll is called:

The following will give a correct size for newStyles before the addAll is called but a 0 size after it is cleared:

```
public void setStyles(ArrayList<String[][]> newStyles) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setStyles: mStyles.size() = " + mStyles.size());
    Log.d(TAG, "setStyles: newStyles.size() = " + newStyles.size());

    mStyles.clear();
    mStyles.addAll(newStyles);

    Log.d(TAG, "setStyles: mStyles.size() = " + mStyles.size());
    Log.d(TAG, "setStyles: newStyles.size() = " + newStyles.size());
}
```

What ends up happening is both ArrayLists end up having a size of 0.

**UPDATE**

I solved it by using:

```
mStyles = new ArrayList<String[][]>(newStyles);
```

But i still want to know what happened so here's the necessary info

Following is within Activity:

```
ArrayList<String[][]> mStyles;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
mStyles = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
....
}

// Called by StylesFragment to preLoad styles from the file when
// the Fragment is viewed
public ArrayList<String[][]> getStylesFromFile() {

    mStyles.clear();
    mStyles.addAll(mTotalsFragment.getStyles());

    return mStyles;
}

// Called by StylesFragment when changes are made to styles
public void setStyles(ArrayList<String[][]> newStyles) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setStyles: mStyles.size() = " + mStyles.size());
    Log.d(TAG, "setStyles: newStyles.size() = " + newStyles.size());

    mStyles.clear();
    mStyles.addAll(newStyles);

    Log.d(TAG, "setStyles: mStyles.size() = " + mStyles.size());
    Log.d(TAG, "setStyles: newStyles.size() = " + newStyles.size());
}
```

Following is within Totals Fragment:

```
ArrayList<String[][]> mStyles;

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
mStyles = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
...
}

public void loadEstimate() {
...
// Do loop here to pull data from a file
mStyle = ...
...
}

// Called by StylesFragment via Activity
// to get Loaded data from file
public ArrayList<String[][]> getStyles() {

    return mStyles;
}

public void saveEstimate() {
...
// Get the styles that should be in Activity
mStyles = ((PagerActivityFragment)getActivity()).getStyles();

// Save the file with the new information
...
}
```

Following is within StylesFragment:

```
ArrayList<String[][]> mStyles;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
mStyles = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
...
}

public void onResume() {
...
// Pull the styles loaded from the file through Activity
mStyles = ((PagerActivityFragment)getActivity()).getStylesFromFile();
...
}

public modifyStyle(stylePos) {
...
// Do some stuff here to modify a specific style (String[][]) within the ArryaList

// Now send changes back to Activity so TotalsFragment can pull it
// even if this Fragment is not available when file is to be saved
((PagerActivityFragment)getActivity()).setStyles(mStyles);
}
```

Comment: maybe mStyles and newStyles point to the same ArrayList?

Comment: If we see a complete program (short as possible) we can confirm, but I'd wager @SašaŠijak is right

Comment: Or you can confirm by putting the line `Log.d(TAG, " Saša Šijak is right: " +  mStyles==newStyles);` at the end

Comment: Hmmm. Never crossed my mind. I just figured since I called setStyles from a Fragment there would be no connections.

Comment: I will post as much as possible showing where newStyles comes from...

Comment: A quick and dirty test would be instead of doing `clear()` do `mStyles = new ArrayList<String[][]>(newStyles);`. You don't see `addAll` if that works then `mStyles` and `newStyles` were the same object.

Comment: Ali, did exactly that. But if possible, I'd still like to understand how they became the same.

Comment: And if that's the case then I'm doing unnecessary things in my program, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return mStyles` in `getStylesFromFile()` in `Activity` is returning the reference to the list `mStyles` which is why the two point to the same List.

Comment: So then is it safe to say when return is used, you're not passing the information within the variable but the variables itself?

Comment: For objects, yes but for primitives, it returns the value.